# Count Distinct Records and

Tags: sql, excel

I have a very large database and I need to extract information from 3 columns:

**I am trying to determine how many unique customers the user is processing.**

1. Username. This is unique name.
2. CustomerNumber. A customer number will appear on many lines, as they could have ordered many products and each product is a line.
3. Date Range. I need to be able to define a date range.

The code I am tried and searched is counting the customer numbers, but not just the distinct customer number.
I have not tried the date range as yet.
I have attached 2 images to show an example of the database and the end result. We used a pivot table to produce this result, but the data changes all the time and we dont want to create a pivot table the whole time.

[Image of Sample Data in Excel:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7Aqj.jpg)

[Image of Required Final Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVQMv.jpg)

```
SELECT `'All data$'`.Username, Count(`'All data$'`.CustomerNumber)
FROM `C:\Users\rhynto\Desktop\Darren Qwix\QWIX_PICKED.xlsx`.`'All data$'`      `'All data$'`
GROUP BY `'All data$'`.Username
```

I will appreciate any advice on this please.

Comment: have you tried using DISTINCT on CustomerNumber?          SELECT `'All data$'`.Username, Count(DISTINCT(`'All data$'`.CustomerNumber))
FROM `C:\Users\rhynto\Desktop\Darren Qwix\QWIX_PICKED.xlsx`.`'All data$'`      `'All data$'`
GROUP BY `'All data$'`.Username

Comment: Maybe this [article](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/beyond-excel/group-by-and-aggregate-sql-functions/) will help you. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759695/group-data-using-sql-group-by-function-in-excel-vba) is another one, too.

Comment: @Ralph Just tested it, and I can definitely do `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` queries via ADO on an Excel spreadsheet. I'm not saying they're the right way or the fastest way, but they certainly do work.

Comment: @SumeetGupta It seems that your comment is not a comment but rather a solution. Why don't you post it as such? Here is an Excel file to verify it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4kar22ew3j3o4sd/Excel%20VBA%20ADO%20-%20Select%20Distinct%20from%20Excel%20file%20%28group%20by%29.xlsm?dl=0